# creating multipolygon from a list of long lat in sf package r

Tags: r, r-sf

i have two lists containing long lats like below

```
> typeof(sec1)
[1] "list"
> sec1
         lon      lat
1   10.77996 76.51189
2   10.78049 76.51223
3   10.78101 76.51257
4   10.78154 76.51290
5   10.78206 76.51324
6   10.78259 76.51358
7   10.78271 76.51357

> typeof(sec2)
[1] "list"
> sec2
         lon      lat
1   10.77224 76.65794
2   10.77090 76.65812
3   10.76956 76.65830
4   10.76821 76.65848
5   10.76687 76.65866
6   10.76552 76.65884
7   10.76559 76.65886
8   10.76566 76.65889
9   10.76574 76.65892
```

i want to create a multipolygon geometry using sf package in R.

as per the documentation i need to pass on a list of list of numeric matrix  to st_multipolygon function ... but it seems to have no option of crs conversion

my attempt below

```
> a<-st_multipolygon(list(sec1,sec2))
Error in vapply(y, ncol, 0L) : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0
```

fails..

i know i am doing some fundamental mistake ..can someone help please

thanks

Comment: Are your `sec1` and `sec2` objects actually lists or `data.frames`? (i.e., try `typeof(data.frame())` ). Use `dput(sec1)` and `dput(sec2)` to share your data

Comment: thanks i think i got the hint.. the dput is telling that they are of calss data.frame...

Comment: so guess i need to convert them to vectors of long lat.. and crete two separate list of them.. and then using this create the geometry..post that i need to convert it to sfc with crs... is that right?

Comment: You might be able to do `mp <- sf::st_multipolygon(x = list(as.matrix(sec1), as.matrix(sec2))`, and then `sf::st_sfc(mp)`

Comment: now my dput looks like  > dput(sec1)
list(c(10.77996083, 76.51189278), c(10.7804860757556, 76.5122294885443
), c(10.7810113472407, 76.512566195987), c(10.781536644457, 76.5129029023281).... but i get > sectorpolygon<-st_multipolygon(list(sec1,sec2))
Error in vapply(y, ncol, 0L) : values must be length 1..

Comment: no worries finally resolved using rbind and list..finally sec1 looks like > sec1
[[1]]
             [,1]     [,2]
         10.77996 76.51189
newpoint 10.78049 76.51223
newpoint 10.78101 76.51257
newpoint 10.78154 76.51290
newpoint 10.78206 76.51324... and all is well...thnks  SymbolixAU for showing me the way

Comment: You're welcome. In the future you should edit your question with the output of `dput()`, rather than put them in the comments. Using `dput()` allows other people to simply copy & paste your data so they can use it in their own R sessions to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This was almost exactly what I wanted to do, so I took these lists and worked on them a bit.  The resulting polygons weren't the best (a few points must have been left out of the original question), but I succeeded with this tactic:

`sec1 <- list(
  rbind(c(10.77996, 76.51189),
        c(10.78049,76.51223),
        c(10.78101,76.51257),
        c(10.78154,76.51290),
        c(10.78206,76.51324),
        c(10.78259,76.51358),
        c(10.78271,76.51357),
        c(10.77996, 76.51189))
)`

sec2 <- list(
   rbind(c(10.77224,76.65794),
   c(10.77090,76.65812),
   c(10.76956,76.65830),
   c(10.76821,76.65848),
   c(10.76687,76.65866),
   c(10.76552,76.65884),
   c(10.76559,76.65886),
   c(10.76566,76.65889),
   c(10.76574,76.65892),
   c(10.77224,76.65794))
)

a <- st_multipolygon(list(sec1,sec2))

plot(a)

> dput(sec1)

`list(structure(c(10.77996, 10.78049, 10.78101, 10.78154, 10.78206, 
10.78259, 10.78271, 10.77996, 76.51189, 76.51223, 76.51257, 76.5129, 
76.51324, 76.51358, 76.51357, 76.51189), .Dim = c(8L, 2L)))`

> dput(sec2)

`list(structure(c(10.77224, 10.7709, 10.76956, 10.76821, 10.76687, 
10.76552, 10.76559, 10.76566, 10.76574, 10.77224, 76.65794, 76.65812, 
76.6583, 76.65848, 76.65866, 76.65884, 76.65886, 76.65889, 76.65892, 
76.65794), .Dim = c(10L, 2L)))`